# How to access Azure Storage via VPN? Private Endpoint?

Tags: azure-storage, vpn

I have VM in On-premise VMWare environment, Azure Virtual Network Gateway and Azure Storage.

I would like to access from Azure Storage Explorer in on-premise VM to Azure Storage via VPN without using public internet.

Is Private Endpoint of Storage and bastion of VNet the best practice?

Does it limit using public internet access to for other usage?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer is a standalone app. You could access storage resources through Azure RBAC and ensure the network is connected between the on-premises network and the Azure virtual network.

As far as I know, Storage Explorer uses HTTPS by default and there is no limit to use the public Internet, you can enable the private endpoint for your Storage Account and set up the VPN connection. You also need to assign your account to access the blob, table, or other service endpoints with enough permission.

For more information:

- [Azure Storage Explorer troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows%2C2004#azure-rbac-permissions-issues)
- [Azure Storage Explorer security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-security)